# In openlayers is there an easy way to simplify the vertices in a drawn polygon?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, openstreetmap

I noticed in openlayers they have a built in feature to simplify the vertices for LineString but I do not see anything for polygons.  Is there an easy way to do this?
Here is the example for the linestring.  http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/simplify-linestring.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polygon consists of an [OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.getArea) which is basically a special LineString that is closed. This means you could just convert your Polygon into a LineString. Like this:

```
var originalAsLinearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(originalPolygon.components[0].components);
var originalAsLineString = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(originalAsLinearRing.components);
```

Then simplify the LineString as shown in the example and convert the LineString back into a Polygon. I am sure there is a more elegant way, but this works as well.

Comment: Once I have the simplified linestring how do i convert it back to the polygon?

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle based on Martin's answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/gdonarum/wxnd5gom/

```
var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(original.components[0].components);
var lineString = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(linearRing.components); 
var newLineString = lineString.simplify(tolerance);
var newLinearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(newLineString.getVertices());
var newPolygon = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon(newLinearRing);
var reducedFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(newPolygon);
```